# What happens if we use a hot-wire voltmeter in a DC circuit instead of an AC circuit?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, instrument

What happens when we use a hot-wire voltmeter to measure voltage across a resistor in a DC circuit?
Does it show the root-mean-square voltage or does it show the mean voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Since a hot wire meter will inherently have a low resistance and use to measure currents of 10s of milliamps and above its use as a voltmeter is rather limited.

The scale on such a meter is non linear and would be calibrated to read rms values as for the operation of this device you are relying on the heating effect of an electric current $\propto I^2R$.

I have just found this [extract from a book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jEM8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA930&lpg=PA930&dq=hot%20wire%20ammeter%20radio%20frequency&source=bl&ots=WEdOnk8UFL&sig=IfAT_uxFHP7p0REOwqxIx2WbvDY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZqKnMzPrOAhUKIcAKHTzLDNsQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=hot%20wire%20ammeter%20radio%20frequency&f=false) which may be of use to you?

Comment: Farcher, I'm having some issues in understanding the first paragraph. Why is it not possible to use a hot-wire instrument as a voltmeter if we could connect a really high resistor in series to the platinum wire? This would essentially be same as of connecting a high resistance in series with a galvanometer to convert it to a voltmeter in DC circuits.

Comment: If you connect a *really high resistance in series* with the galvanometer think of the sort of voltages which will be required to drive 10s of millions through the galvanometer.